# Polars: Naming Dataframe Columns when using scan_csv on headerless CSVs

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, python-polars

It doesn't look like Polars' `scan_csv` supports user provided column names. This can make it a little awkward to work with headerless CSVs because you then have to either mutate your data for Polars or load with `read_csv` which has the `new_columns` argument (and while `new_columns` achieves the desired outcome its name makes it feel like isn't necessarily intended for use this way).

What is the current best way for working with headerless CSVs in Polars? Were there design decisions at play in not releasing Polars' with a `columns_names` or `headers` arg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
a `new_columns` parameter [has been added to `.scan_csv`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/7642)

It should be available in the next release: `0.16.15`

---

I see `has_header` and `with_column_names`: [docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html#polars-scan-csv)

```
>>> pl.scan_csv("/tmp/*.csv", has_header=False).collect()
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_1 | column_2 | column_3 │
│ ---      | ---      | ---      │
│ i64      | i64      | str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1        | 1        | a        │
│ 2        | 1        | b        │
│ 1        | 1        | a        │
│ 2        | 1        | b        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

```
>>> pl.scan_csv("/tmp/.*csv", has_header=False, with_column_names=lambda cols: ["one", "two", "three"]).collect()
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ one | two | three │
│ --- | --- | ---   │
│ i64 | i64 | str   │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 1   | 1   | a     │
│ 2   | 1   | b     │
│ 1   | 1   | a     │
│ 2   | 1   | b     │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘
```